# Circuit explanation with short circuit and independent current source

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, current-source, short-circuit

[image: circuit]

I have trouble applying KVL to this circuit. I am trying to find the current that passes through the 5 Ω resistance but I don't know what to do. I know that the capacitor and the inductor are connected in parallel. Is there any way I could simplify the circuit?

Comment: The 5Ohm resistor is shorted, look closely at the circuit. The two reactive bipoles are in parallel with each other and also with the current generator. Therefore no current flows in the resistor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5 Ω resistor **is** shorted out hence, there will be zero current flowing through it.

Comment: this is true because it is connected in parrallel to the short circuit , right ?

Comment: @math_noob that's what my answer says. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.